# GeoServer v2.5.2, webadmin, missing WMS and styles menu

Tags: geoserver, wms, style

After installing GeoServer v2.5.2 we are missing the Styles and WMS menus.
Does anybody seen this, have a clue whats wrong?

(The WMS server is working, just the webadmin interface not working.)

[image: Simple image to show missing menu items WMS and Styles]

---

**EDIT** some more details about installation:

- MS Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit SP1
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)


  <sub>- GEOSERVER_HOME=C:\GeoServer\2.5.2
  - XX:MaxPermSize=512m
  - Initial Java Heap Size 512MB
  - Maximum Java Heap Size 1024MB</sub>

GeoServer is installed from zip-archive

Extensions: mysql, gdal, dxf-core

Only 1 small tweak to: OpenLayersMapTemplate.ftl

Installed as Service with Wrapper v3.5.19

Same type of installation as with previous versions (se directories below, all worked fine, only 2 or 3 versions live)

[image: Geoserver directories]

Comment: I can't reproduce with zip file installation on Windows 7. Tell more details: Installation methot, operating system, jre/jdk version, installation directory if on Windows.